# How Liquibase rollback when execution failed?

Tags: liquibase

If i run change log file that contain multiple change set from command line and it failed because of wrong sql at say change set 2. So change set 1 has executed and committed then how will i rollback this change using liquibase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to use the rollbackCount command. Running "liquibase rollbackCount 1" will roll back the last changeSet executed using either the specified `<rollback>` block in the changeSet or by figuring it out if Liquibaes can based on the information in the changeSet. For example, a createTable command has the information needed to create a `drop table` statement, but a dropTable command does not have the information needed to do a `create table` so you would need to specify your own rollback block.

Comment: "liquibase rollbackCount 1" only rollback last successful changeset. But suppose if 2 or more changeset executed successful then how would i know the rollback count value.

Comment: There is also rollbackToDate where you specify a date and rollback where you specify a tag set by a previous "tag" command you can use